# Empty rows not showing as empty rows using CountA

Tags: vba, excel

Why does the following VBA script not show any message boxes when row 4, 5 and 6 are all empty...

```
Sub Test()
LastRow = 40

For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1
    Set myRange = Range("B" & i & ":T" & i)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Empty " & Cells(i, 1).Row
    Else
        x = x
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the worksheet formula return 0? Note: not all that are blank to the naked eye are blank, e.g. nullstrings, ";;;" format numbers.

Comment: @user3819867 Ahh it's because column E has a formula in it, how can I skip over that specific column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can seem to do it is a slow way:

```
LastRow = Range("B:Z").Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1
    BlankRow = False
    For j = 2 To LastColumn
        If Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
            Blank = False
            Exit For
        End If
        BlankRow = True
    Next j
    If BlankRow = True Then
        x = x
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Just test both column ranges:

```
Sub Test()
    LastRow = 40

    For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1
        count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B"&i & ":D"&i))
        count = count + WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("F"&i & ":T"&i))    
        If count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Empty " & i
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**edit:** or build a range object which contains the two column ranges, intersect that with the last row, and move this range object in the loop. This way, you don't build the range object anew in each iteration:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range, colrng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    LastRow = 40

    Set colrng = Application.Union(Range("B:D"), Range("F:T"))
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(colrng, Rows(LastRow))
    For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Empty row: " & i
        End If
        Set rng = rng.Offset(-1, 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

As good practice, always declare your variables, and use `long` integers for row or column indices.

Comment: The top one works nicely but, isn't there a way to ignore the formula columns (to check the values of the range maybe?)

Comment: -? Both subroutines skip over column E completely, as you've required in your comment. The second code is only a variation where you can insert multiple, non-contiguous column ranges in a slightly better readable way. This way, you could even skip multiple (formula) columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()
LastRow = 40

For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1
    Set myRange = Range("B" & i & ":T" & i)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myRange,"<>") = 0 Then 'count where it's not a null or empty string
        MsgBox "Empty " & Cells(i, 1).Row
    Else
        x = x
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work at all because I have a formula in one of the columns, I want it to ignore the formulas.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up big time... It's `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myRange,"") - myRange.Cells.Count = 0`. you count all that's empty (or null), that's easily doable and then substract the cell count. If the cell count is greater than the number of non-blank cells, then there must be something in there. I see you've already found an answer but seek to learn more, kudos to that.